# How to isolate a URL' domain name in the absence of "https" or "www"?

Tags: javascript

I've been isolating URLs' domain names thus:

```
return new URL(myUrl).hostname.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i, '')
```

However URLs lacking "https" or "www" (e.g: `bla.blablabla.blabla.com/something/?id=616&md=3&no=A4`) trigger this error message:

> "Failed to construct 'URL'"

How can I accomodate such URLs and still isolate the domain name from them?

Comment: Simply prepend them with `https://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check `url` string for example if it contains `"https" or "http"` protocol, if it doesn't contain then prefix the "https" protocol in your url string.
For checking the protocol you can use `RegExp.test()` method by using regular expression.

```js
const validUrl = "https://www.google.com"
const invalidUrl = "bla.blablabla.blabla.com/something/?id=616&md=3&no=A4";

const getFormattedHost = (urlStr) => {
  const regex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i;
  const isValid = /^https?:\/\//.test(urlStr);
  let finalUrl = !isValid ? `https://${urlStr}` : urlStr;
  return new URL(finalUrl).hostname.replace(regex, "");
}

console.log(getFormattedHost(validUrl));
console.log(getFormattedHost(invalidUrl));
```